# Showing Contextual Action Bar in front on TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, contextual-action-bar

I have a screen with TabLayout (Using Android Design Support library) at the top and a ListView below it. I don't have any Action Bar.

[image: Screenshot]

Whenever I select one or more Items of ListView I show Contextual Action Bar to perform some operations on selected rows. The CAB is shown above TabLayout. It seems like whole screen is shifted downwards which is not a good user experience. I want to show the CAB in front of TabLayout. The tabs should be behind CAB.

Below is my expected output:

[image: Screenshot2]

Please help me out. How can I show CAB in front of TabLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:windowActionModeOverlay` to true in your theme. If you're using the AppCompat library, set `windowActionModeOverlay` in your app's attribute namespace to true.